# How can I remove the previous and next links on the first and last pages in Stacey v3 with Twig?

Tags: templates, hyperlink, twig

I'm editing the `project.html` template in Stacey v3, there's next and previous links generated by:

`{% include 'partials/next-page.html' %}`

and

`{% include 'partials/previous-page.html' %}`

In `next-page.html`:

```
{% for sibling in page.next_sibling %}
  <li><a href="{{ sibling.url }}" title="{{ sibling.title }}">Next project</a>: &rarr; {{ sibling.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

And in `previous-page.html`:

```
{% for sibling in page.previous_sibling %}
  <li><a href="{{ sibling.url }}" title="{{ sibling.title }}">Previous project</a>: &larr; {{ sibling.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

They work fine, they do their job, the issue for me is on the first project page it has a link to a previous page like `<li><a href="" title="">Previous project</a>: ← </li>`, which goes nowhere.

On the last page of the projects it creates `<li><a href="" title="">Next project</a>: → </li>`

These dead links I don't want, they're misleading and pointless.

So I'm trying to get rid of them with the logic of, if its the first page, don't generate the previous link, and on the last page don't generate a next link.

I had tried something like this:

```
{% for sibling in page.siblings %}
    {% if loop.first == False %}
        Nothing should be generated
            {% else %}
        {% include 'partials/next-page.html' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Which doesn't work, nor is my understanding of the logic sound.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you’re doing the opposite of what you want here:

```
{% if loop.first == False %}
    Nothing should be generated
```

You should just do

```
{% if loop.first %}
    Nothing should be generated
```

You want it to apply when the loop is the first one.

**Update:** Try this instead:

```
{% for sibling in page.siblings %}
    {% if sibling is null %}
        Nothing should be generated
    {% else %}
        {% include 'partials/next-page.html' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Second update:** It seems there’s a backend conception issue… If a page does not exist it should render null. Here, is seems to render a page object with empty attributes (url, title…).
It should be fixed. For now, could this do the trick?

```
{% for sibling in page.siblings %}
    {% if (sibling.url is null) or (sibling.url is empty) %}
        Nothing should be generated
    {% else %}
        {% include 'partials/next-page.html' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it's now repeating the next page link as many times as the amount of projects I have :(

Comment: It's still doing it :(

Comment: Strange. Can you do a `{{ dump(sibling) }}` ?
`{% for sibling in page.siblings %}
        {{ dump(sibling) }}
    {% endfor %}`

Comment: `The function "dump" does not exist in "project.html" at line 54`

Comment: Oh. Do you know the twig version you’re using ? Mmm… It’s not available by default actually. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html

Comment: Nope, same deal again, just repeats the next project name, let's call it Example Project, 7 times.

None of this is wanted.

What's really wanted is on the first page in my projects folder to not render the previous page link at the bottom, and for the last page in my projects folder to not render the next page link at the bottom.

Comment: It's not that a page doesn't exist it should render nothing, its that the page is generating previous and next links that go to `" "` which is almost like its linking to pages before the first page (non existent) and after the last page (nothing is after it).

What its doing is 'oh this is the first page, so there's nothing before it, and since this is as far back as you can go then I'll link to myself'

And the opposite with the last page, it's going 'I'm the last next page, so I'll link to myself I'm as next page as you can get'.

Hope that makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the contents of templates/partials/next-page.html with:

```
{% if page.is_last %}
<p>&nbsp;</p>
{% else %}
{% for sibling in page.next_sibling %}
  <p><a href="{{ sibling.url }}">Next project</a>: &rarr; {{ sibling.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

And

Replace the contents of templates/partials/previous-page.html with:

```
{% if page.is_first %}
<p>&nbsp;</p>
{% else %}
{% for sibling in page.previous_sibling %}
  <p><a href="{{ sibling.url }}">Previous project</a>: &larr; {{ sibling.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```